# How does angular eagerly loading a component without registering into the declarations array

Tags: angular

Here is my feature component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-polling',
  templateUrl: './polling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./polling.component.scss']
})
export class PollingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here is the Routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PollingComponent } from './polling/polling.component';

const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PollingComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the Root module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

In the above code you can see that the **PollingComponent** is never added into the declarations array, but the component is loading in the browser without having any errors. So, I wondered how does the component is loading without registering it? I am using Angular CLI 12.2.3.

Comment: I’ve seen more questions about this. It seems there was a change in ng12.x that would allow this.

Comment: Quriosity, has you check if still work when you build in prod: `ng build`?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code means you are saying PollingComponent has not added in Root Module but component is loading fine without issue.
See try to understand what Root module is doing there, its a root or main module of the application so here root module contains default main component that is AppComponent and to use routing module is importing AppRoutingModule. In AppRoutingModule routs is declared as PollingComponent so it is expected logic, no need to register PollingComponent in Root Module because PollingComponent has registered in AppRoutingModule. It will work without any issue. Thanks

Comment: `PolllingComponent` is NOT declared/registered in `AppRoutingModule`, it is only present in the routes.

Comment: but router modules are added into the imports array of App module. Also the component is not lazy loaded, so it should be added into the declaration section right?

Comment: Hi Gael J ,To present that PollingComponent in AppRoutingModule  see the code AppRoutingModule he has used this import { PollingComponent } from './polling/polling.component'; Here import saying if you want to use some properties of a componet then you have to register first as import way.

Comment: @Rajesh You are confusing typescript imports with Angular module imports/declarations. Having a typescript import has nothing to do with Angular loading components.

Comment: @Pranab PollingComponent is used in AppRoutingModule  for routing. So here in this code " imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)] " you are asking Angular to instantiate an instance of the Router class globally so PoolingComponent will load no need to use this component in declaration.

Comment: @GaëlJ Component will load if you are using that component in router, this code "imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]" will help to load that component, you do not need to write in module declaration section.

Comment: @RajeshKumarSwain did u find any reference/documents that tells about how to load components without declarations. If yes, please share it here.

Comment: @Pranab I just tried on your above code, I have no specific document now. You can also try this. In one way Create a new component but don't add that in routes and in declaration section. See what happening, this time you will get exception. And another way you have already faced that is your current pooling component used in routing. Hope you are clear my clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this:
if you do not declare the component it cannot access the elements of the imported modules

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).